# Unable to dismiss authentication popup with java webdriver

Tags: java, authentication, webdriver, alert, freeze

I am unable to dismiss the dialogue when retrieving pages with authentication. See example below:

```
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
webDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(1, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES);
webDriver.get("http://sv2.biz/")
try {
    Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept()
    alert.dismiss()
} catch (Exception e) {
    //do nothing
}
```

The webDriver hangs unable to use. The webDriver does not timeout so it is never returned to the grid when killing the java process.

Comment: Try setting the authentication headers in your HTTP requests.  Are you using BASIC AUTH?

Comment: Empty catch block?  Bad idea.  You should at least log it.  You have no idea if something else is wrong.

Comment: this is webdriver not Http get. I do not believe there is an auth.
Empty catch because it is the generic case that does not have a popup

Answer (score 1):

Selenium cannot interact with basic auth popup boxes.  Instead you will need to intercept the network traffic and add a basic auth header using a proxy.

My personal preference is the [browsermob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy).

To hook it into selenium you will need to do something like this:

```
final String basicAuthKey = "base64_encoded_username_and_password";

BrowserMobProxy browserMobProxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
browserMobProxy.start();
browserMobProxy.addRequestFilter(new RequestFilter() {
    @Override
    public HttpResponse filterRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo) {
        request.headers().add("Authorization", basicAuthKey);

        return null;
    }
});
Proxy proxySettings = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserMobProxy, InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress());
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(PROXY, proxySettings);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Obviously you are going to need to work out what the basic auth key that will be used is, the easiest way to do this is have a look at your network traffic after authorising and seeing what the "Authorisation" header has been set to.  You can also encode you username/password manually if you prefer.  For more info on basic auth click [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Answer (score 0):

If that is Authentication popup you can use username and password with your application url like below:

```
https://username:password@www.sv2.biz
```

Let me know if it not work.

Comment: This will not work in all browsers.  Most browser manufacturers disabled this by default ages ago because it was seen as a security risk.

Comment: Yes, like IE directly it will not support you should add iexploere in registry, rest of the browser it will work.

Comment: You really shouldn't start hacking the registry in an attempt to make what is effectively a hack work.